# Warning in Jest: 'Native module not found/exported - are you sure its linked properly?'

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs

I have a react-native expo **bare workflow** app where I'm seeing a warning in my console ***only when running tests in jest*** the packages in question work when used in my app (tested unimodules works via using the Constants in there), and I've re-followed the instructions to set them up multiple times: https://docs.expo.io/bare/installing-unimodules/

These warnings don't prevent my app running or my tests, but they clog up the terminal as they repeat for every set of tests making it a struggle to read. (I'm aware I can run jest with the --silent flag but this will obviously hide all the other output like actual errors e.g. wrap in `act(() => { })` errors)

The warnings:

```
  console.warn
    The "UMNativeModulesProxy" native module is not exported through NativeModules; verify that @unimodules/react-native-adapter's native code is linked properly

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@unimodules/react-native-adapter/src/NativeModulesProxy.native.ts:41:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@unimodules/react-native-adapter/src/index.ts:2:1)

 console.warn
    No native ExponentConstants module found, are you sure the expo-constants's module is linked properly?

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/expo-constants/src/Constants.ts:25:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/expo-asset/src/PlatformUtils.ts:3:1)
```

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @sathwik unfortunately not, in the end all I've done is set `console.warn = () => {}` inside of my `setup.native.js` (my jest config is set to load this under `setupFilesAfterEnv`) to suppress the warns without silencing errors as the  `- - silent` flag would

Comment: Ok thank you, I have the same issue! Guess I'll do the same too :)